# Zorn's lemma in categorical language

Tags: category-theory, axiom-of-choice

The axiom of choice, which is equivalent to Zorn's Lemmma, has a nice categorical "translation": in the category of sets, every epi is a retraction.

So the axiom of choice says something about the structure of the category of sets.

Can Zorn's lemma be equally simply translated into categorical language?
For example, does Zorn's lemma say something about the category of posets (and order preserving functions) or another well-known category.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/113859

Comment: Inventor of WildCats, please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54837418/how-should-this-plugin-system-of-diagram-transformations-work and comment if you'd like to work together on it.

Answer (score 7):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but, since any poset can be made into a category by making the elements of the poset the objects of the category and making exactly one morphism $a\rightarrow b$ if $a\le b$, and none otherwise, we can turn Zorn's lemma into a statement about categories.

Here is a translation of Zorn's lemma into categorical language, using this correspondence:

> If $\mathcal{C}$ is a poset and, for any totally ordered set $\mathcal{I}$ and functor $F: \mathcal{I} \mapsto \mathcal{C}$, $F$ has a <s>colimit</s> cocone, then there is an object in $\mathcal{C}$ whose only outward morphisms are isomorphisms.

You can't just use the more standard categorical notion of final object, because Zorn's lemma only guarantees the existence of a maximal object, not a maximum one. (Thanks to Zhen Lin for pointing this out).

Comment: Replace "colimit" by "cocone" in order to get the usual version.

Comment: @WilliamBallinger That's not quite correct. A maximal element in the sense of Zorn's lemma is not necessarily a maximum element.

Answer (score 2):

There is a categorical version of Zorn's lemma.

For any small category $\mathcal{C}$, if every totally ordered set $\mathcal{I}$ and every functor $F : \mathcal{I} \rightarrow C$ has a cocone, then there is an object $M$ such that for any object $A$ of $\mathcal{C}$ if there is a map $M \rightarrow A$ then there is also a map $A \rightarrow M$.

To prove this theorem, first use the regular zorn's lemma to find a maximal element $\mathcal{I}$ in the poset of subcategories of $\mathcal{C}$ that are a total order, i.e. every hom set has at most one element, and every pair of objects $A$ and $B$ are either equal, or there is either a map $A \rightarrow B$ in $\mathcal{I}$ or a map $B \rightarrow A$ in $\mathcal{I}$ but not in both directions.

The cocone $M$ of $\mathcal{I}$, is the maximal object of $C$ that we are looking for. To prove it is maximal let $A$ be an object with a map $M \rightarrow A$. Then if $A$ is not in $\mathcal{I}$ we can construct a longer chain than $\mathcal{I}$ by adjoining $A$. Therefore $A \in \mathcal{I}$, so there is a map $A \rightarrow M$.

This version can be used to construct an algebebraic closure of a field. The category of algebraic extensions of a field $K$ is small and has filtered colimits, therefore there is a maximal element.